# Possibility to convert ppd from OSX to CentOS linux

Tags: centos, cups, canon

I have one issue and that is, I cannot set our plotter to work with cups server. I have Canon imagePROGRAPH iPF755 Plotter machine and I have set CentOS 7.6 to be a print server for all our printers. I wanted to set this plotter on CentOS as well. Trying to set this network plotter, I found out that there are no native canon drivers for that, so I went to see if there are possibilities for extracting ppd file from OSX .pkg 
Unfortunately ppd file has some directives which are different from linux system, so I cannot simply import it to cups as paths are different, and there are some drivers/modules/filters which are not compatible...

Is there any possibility to convert or modify this ppd file to work with CentOS?

Whole PPD file can be found in pastebin link:
[iPF755 - ppd](https://pastebin.com/ujRQV0R1)

Or are there any other drivers that I could use, that are "compatible" with Canon imagePROGRAPH iPF755?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find something that works...

If someone needs the same thing, You can download a text file and save it as ppd.

```
https://pastebin.com/QbejTnVc
```